# convert data frame column containing different date formats to Date object

Tags: regex, r, date

I have a data frame column of class `character` containing different date formats:

```
foo=data.frame(Date=c("29-Jan-16","29-Jan-16","2/5/2016","2/5/2016"),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I would like to convert the column `Date` to a vector of class `Date` objects. I can correctly parse each format separately:

```
> as.Date( foo$Date, format = "%d-%b-%y" )
[1] "2016-01-29" "2016-01-29" NA           NA          
> as.Date( foo$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y" )
[1] NA           NA           "2016-02-05" "2016-02-05"
```

So I thought to join the two parsing instructions with `ifelse` and `grepl`. Note that `grepl` correctly identifies the rows where the first format is used

```
> grepl("-",foo$Date)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

However, the complet instruction doesn't work:

```
bar = foo
bar$Date=ifelse(grepl("-",foo$Date),
                      as.Date( foo$Date, format = "%d-%b-%y" ),
                      as.Date( foo$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y" ))

> bar
   Date
1 16829
2 16829
3 16836
4 16836
```

Questions:

1. Can you help me understand what's happening?
2. Even if I manage to fix my solution with your help, I learn more about R and that's great, but the solution remains suboptimal. The reason is that the "brilliant" person who populates the dataframe may choose to use even more date formats (it has already happened before, and it will likely happen again). I will then have to nest more `ifelse`, and create more complex regexps. The code will soon become nasty and unreadable. Isn't there a way to have R automatically find the right data format for each element of `foo$Date`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be easier to work with `lubridate`.  Assuming that the format of the 'Date' is in the order day, month, year, we can use `dmy`.

```
library(lubridate)
dmy(foo$Date)
#[1] "2016-01-29 UTC" "2016-01-29 UTC" "2016-05-02 UTC" "2016-05-02 UTC"
```

In case there are other variations in the order, we can also use `guess_formats` with `parse_date_time`.

```
 with(foo, parse_date_time(Date, 
         orders=guess_formats(Date, c('dby', 'mdy'))))
 #[1] "2016-01-29 UTC" "2016-01-29 UTC" "2016-02-05 UTC" "2016-02-05 UTC"
```

---

Regarding the use of `ifelse` in the OP's code, the output we get in the `numeric` class can be converted back to `Date` class

```
v1 <- ifelse(grepl("-",foo$Date),
                  as.Date( foo$Date, format = "%d-%b-%y" ),
                  as.Date( foo$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y" ))

as.Date(v1, origin='1970-01-01')
#[1] "2016-01-29" "2016-01-29" "2016-02-05" "2016-02-05"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick and clear answer! Unfortunately, while the first format is indeed day, month, year, the second is not: it's month, day and year (with 4 digits). I installed `lubridate` and had a look at the help, but I'm not familiar with the package and I'm not sure how to combine `parse_date_time` and `guess_formats`. Can you complete your solution using them? Thanks

Comment: @DeltaIV  In that case you may use the `guess_formats`, updated the answer.

Comment: @DeltaIV If there are dates like `2/5/2016` and `5/2/2016` where the first case is `m/d/Y' and the second is `d/m/Y`, it might be difficult.

Comment: thanks a lot! It works now. For what it concerns the difficult case, let's hope that my "supplier" won't get too crazy. If that happens, I'll probably post another question :) thanks again, you really helped me.